# Php rabbitMq consuming daemon failing with mysql broken pipe error

Tags: php, mysql, rabbitmq, propel

I'm currently trying to restore the functionality of an old app and part of functionality I can't restore (honestly I'm even not sure it worked properly before) logic to consume rabbit MQ messages. This app has custom logic to run workers which processing the rabbit messages. The issues are when workers running they always failing on any action with database (get some data, close connection, etc.) whit error `send of 291 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe`. Application using Propel ORM. So first I'll share propel configurations file:

config.propel.php:

```
<?php
use Propel\Runtime\Propel;
use Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionManagerSingle;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$loggerConfig = $config->get('logger')['sql'];
$db = $config->get('db');
$env = $config->get('app')['env'];

$defaultLogger = new Logger('defaultLogger');
$defaultLogger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($loggerConfig['filename'], $loggerConfig['level']));
Propel::getServiceContainer()->setLogger('defaultLogger', $defaultLogger);

$queryLogger = new Logger('main');
$queryLogger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($loggerConfig['filename'], $loggerConfig['level']));
Propel::getServiceContainer()->setLogger('main', $queryLogger);

$serviceContainer = Propel::getServiceContainer();
$serviceContainer->setAdapterClass('main', 'mysql');

$manager = new ConnectionManagerSingle();

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$db['host'].';';

if (isset($db['port'])) {
    $dsn .= 'port=' . $db['port'] . ";";
} else {
    $dsn .= 'port=3306;';
}

if (isset($db['charset'])) {
    $dsn .= 'charset='.$db['charset'].";";
}

$dsn .= 'dbname='.$db['dbname'];

$manager->setConfiguration([
    'dsn' => $dsn,
    'user'     => $db['user'],
    'password' => $db['password'],
]);

$serviceContainer->setConnectionManager('main', $manager);

if ($env == 'development') {
    $serviceContainer->getWriteConnection('main')->useDebug(true);
}
```

`bootstrap.daemon.php` which is actually used for bootstrapping that worker's application:

```
    <?php

    require 'lib/vendor/autoload.php';
    require 'app/autoload.php';
    // app config is just set of configurations like database credentials etc. 
    require 'app/config.php';
  // provided above
    require_once 'app/config.propel.php';
```

and the `start` script itself which is starting the worker's daemon:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap.daemon.php';
// it's a routing (not sure why it here)
require __DIR__.'/../../app/config.public.php';

use App;
use Luncher;

App::start($config);

/*
    Here is some magic:)
    Do not change
 */
{
    ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 0);
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 0);
}

$l = new Luncher;
$l->startDeamon();
```

`Launcher`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Daemons\Core;

use App\App;
use App\Daemons\Core\ServiceWrapper;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

class Luncher
{
    private static $daemonsNamespace = "App\Daemons\\";

    public function __construct()
    {
        set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
            $this->out("[ERROR] ". $errstr." at line ".$errline." in file ".$errfile);
            die();
        });
    }


    public function startDeamon($daemonName = 'Deamon)
    {
        $className = self::$daemonsNamespace.$daemonName;
        if (class_exists($className)) {
            $class = new \ReflectionClass($className);

            $logger = new Logger('daemon');
            $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($daemonConfig['log']));

            $serives = new ServiceWrapper($logger);

            // start 5 workers  
            for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
                echo date("d.m.Y H:i")." Starting daemon $daemonName\n";
                $className::start($serives);
            }
        } else {
            echo date("d.m.Y H:i")." Class $className not found!\n";
        }
    }

    private function stopDaemon($daemonName = 'Daemon')
    {
        $daemonPid = $this->getDaemonPids(daemonName);
        if (strlen($daemonPid)) {
            $this->out("Killing daemon $daemonName");
            exec("kill ".$daemonPid);
        }
    }

    private function getDaemonPids($daemonName)
    {
        $result = [];
        $tmp = [];
        exec("pidof daemons.$daemonName", $tmp);

        if (isset($tmp[0])) {
            $result = explode(' ', $tmp[0]);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function out($str)
    {
         echo date("d.m.Y H:i")." $str \n";
    }
}
```

`Deamon` itself:

```
<?php
namespace App\Daemons\Core\Queue;

use App\App;
use Propel\Runtime\Propel;
use App\Daemons\Core\ServiceWrapper;

class Daemon
{
    protected $isParent = true;
    protected $AMQPChannel;
    protected $services;
    protected $currentMsg;
    protected $reinitializeAttempts = 0;
    const MAX_REINITIALIZE_ATTEMPTS = 2;

    public static function start(ServiceWrapper $services)
    {
        $d = new static;
        $d->services = $services;
        $d->fork();

        if ($d->isChild()) {
            $d->services->setPid(getmypid());
            $d->run();
        }
    }


    protected function fork()
    {
        $this->isParent = pcntl_fork();
    }

    protected function isChild()
    {
        if (!$this->isParent) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final protected function run()
    {
        try {
            $fErrorHandler = function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
                $this->error('[ERROR] '.$errstr." at line ".$errline." in file ".$errfile);
                die();
            };
            set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) use ($fErrorHandler) {
                $fErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
            });

            register_shutdown_function(function() use ($fErrorHandler) {
                $error = error_get_last();

                if ($error !== null) {
                    $errno   = $error["type"];
                    $errfile = $error["file"];
                    $errline = $error["line"];
                    $errstr  = $error["message"];
                    $fErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
                }
            });


            $this->_init();

            $callback = function($msg) {
                if (!is_null($msg) && is_array($msg)) {
                    $this->output("Got a new message from queue");
                    $this->output(json_encode($msg));
                    $this->currentMsg = $msg;
                    $this->onNewMessage($msg);
                    $this->currentMsg = null;
                    $this->reinitializeAttempts = 0;
                }
            };

            if ($this->currentMsg) {
                $callback($this->currentMsg);
            }

            $this->consume('long_jobs', $callback);
            $this->runHandling();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->error('[EXCEPTION] '.$e->getMessage()." ".$e->getFile()." : ". $e->getLine());

            /**
             * we can't get error code for PDOException :(
             */
            if ($e instanceof \PDOException || $e instanceof \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException) {
                if ($this->reinitializeAttempts < self::MAX_REINITIALIZE_ATTEMPTS) {
                    $this->output('Trying to reinitialize daemon');
                    $this->reinitializeAttempts++;
                    $this->run();
                    return;
                } else {
                    $this->error('Max reinitialize attempts were achivied');
                }
            }
            die();
        }
    }

    protected function output($msg)
    {
        $this->services->output($msg);
    }

    protected function error($msg)
    {
        $this->services->error($msg);
    }

    protected function onNewMessage($data)
    {
        $this->output("Got a new job");

        $job = new LongJob();


        $this->output("Lunching job ".$data['jobName']);

        $job->setServices($this->services);

        $t1 = microtime(true);
        $job->run($data['data']);
        Propel::closeConnections();
        $this->output("Job is finished. time: ".(microtime(true) - $t1)." seconds");
    }

    private function _init()
    {
        $config = App::getConfig();

        $connection= new AMQPConnection($config->host, $config->port, $config->user, $config->password);
        $this->AMQPChannel = $connection->channel();
    }

    public function consume($queueName, $userCallback)
    {
        $callback = function($msg) use ($userCallback) {
            $userCallback(json_decode($msg->body, true));
            $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
        };
        $this->AMQPChannel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
        $this->AMQPChannel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false);
        $this->AMQPChannel->basic_consume($queueName, '', false, false, false, false, $callback);
    }

    public function runHandling()
    {
        while (count($this->AMQPChannel->callbacks)) {
            $this->channel->wait();
        }

        $this->AMQPChannel->close();
    }
}
```

And `LongJob`:

```
namespace App\Daemons\LongJobs;

use App\Daemons\Core\LongJob;
use App\Models\User;
use App\App;
use App\EventsServer\Core\Event;
use App\EventsServer\Core\EventsManager;
use App\Models\AR\Payments\Payments;
    class LongJob {
        protected $services;
        public function setServices(IServices $services)
        {
            $this->services = $services;
        }

        public function run($data)
        {
            if (!isset($data['userId'])) {
                $this->services->error("There is no user id!");
                return;
            }

            $compatProductId = ProductQuery::create()
                ->filterBySku(Product::SKU_COMPAT)
                ->findOne()
                ->getId();


            $oUser = User::find($data['userId']);

            if (!$oUser) {
                $this->services->error("Can't find user with id ". $data['userId']);
                return;
            }

            $arPurchase = PurchaseQuery::create()
                ->filterByProductId($compatProductId)
                ->find();

            foreach ($arPurchase as $purchase) {
                if ($data['userId'] != $purchase->getUserId()) {
                    $oPurchasedUser = User::find($purchase->getUserId());
                    $oPayments = new Payments($oPurchasedUser);
                    $oPayments->calcAndSaveCompat([$oUser]);
                }
            }
        }
```

And when `LongJob` is running and first usage of database occure it throwing that error. Sorry for a wall of code, but I do not know how else I can share the issue. Honestly code is not very clean and writtern years ago. In my experience I always use rabbit with some of modern frameworks so I'm not very familair with creating such a daemons by own, and I do not khow to solve it :(

Comment: “Broken pipe” means MySQL server has closed connection from its side, so it looks like you will have to re-write the connection code to check if it’s still active and re-connect when necessary.

Comment: I also thought about that, and I tried to caught that PDO exception to re-connect, but I can't catch it. Also as you can see there is already reconnection logic, so I'm assuming that problem was before.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention. Im messages queue is empty, very first message is not failing but all next messages does.

Comment: It’s possible the problem is not with the database but with RabbitMQ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064662/rabbitmq-broken-pipe-error-or-lost-messages . Either way you will need to debug and troubleshoot, read logs and set up logging to determine likely causes. The code quality indeed wishes for better, especially the ability to handle failures and recovering from them.

Comment: I agree that code quality indeed wishes for better :) It's a legacy app and I do not want to refactor it much as in plans is rewriting it. And the issue looks like not in MySQL nor rabbitMq. I made two queries to get user one with pure PDO instance and one with propel, and pdo query working but pdo ones faiing with same broken pipe error

Comment: ```$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $db['user'], $db['password']);
        $sttmnt = $pdo->prepare('select id from users where id = :id');
        $sttmnt->execute([':id' => 34359]);
        $result = $sttmnt->fetchAll();
        $this->output(json_encode($result)); 
        $this->output(User::find(34359));```   `User::find() failing but pure PDO query returning result

Comment: But not sure so far what causing the issue